Windows Icons always square?
I wonder whether the system sizes of icons are always square in Windows. I am referring to the Windows specifications for apps, not the icon bitmaps themselves.
E.g. with the function from the WinAPI GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON) I get the width of a large icon and with GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON) its height. But isn't at least one of these function calls redundant, since icons are always square?
Also, the default file names for icons also only contain one value, e.g. AppList.targetsize-16.png and not AppList.targetsize-16x16.png ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/iconography/app-icon-construction#complete-list-of-icons-and-variations )
To be more precise: is it guaranteed that standard icon sizes in Windows (until at least Windows 11) are always square?

Edit:
Since the question seemed ambiguous: I am currently practicing in C++ with the WinAPI (even if it may be a bit outdated, I am only interested in the theory). When creating applications, there are countless articles, procedures and concepts just for the design of icons and in what size they should be created. If I now want to manage everything myself with the WinAPI and, for example, change the scaling of tray icons to 125%, 20x20 icons are used instead of 16x16.
Is it now sufficient if I query the icon width, get a 20 as a result and can conclude from this that I am now loading the 20x20 icon? I could be so crazy and use a different color for each scaling (even if there is really no reason to do so)
For me, this question is not primarily about the practical benefits, but more about a basic understanding.

The question doesn't make sense. The icon file format allows for non-square images and the system provides API calls to determine the width and height individually. There is no "default file name" for icons, either. The system can display icons of any rectangular shape. Whether Windows' UI and windowing framework(s) set aside a square to render "default" icons is at the implementation's discretion.

Or, in other words: If icons are square that is an artistic choice. It is not enforced by the system itself.

I think the question is will SM_CXICON and SM_CYICON ever return different values.

SM_CXICON and SM_CYICON have lost meaning over the years anyway. Ever since WPF, Office, and Visual Studio went full-on non-standard NC rendering, the ability to gather non-client metrics has plummeted.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can have an icon that appears to be round by having a round image (or a triangle, or any shape) surrounded by pixels with the transparent attribute. In case you saw this -- an Icon that appeared to be round -- that's how it's done. I can't definitively answer whether windows icons are always square, because a quality answer for stackoverflow would require a reference to microsoft documentation, and I'm not up for that search today(sorry).  But yea -- pretty sure -- always square, and probably will be for years and years and years.


is it guaranteed that standard icon sizes in Windows (until at least
Windows 11) are always square?

According to Qualify an image resource for targetsize and Refer to an image file from your app package manifest, It's almost right from my view although they're different project types.
And it can also be deduced from To retrieve the size of the shell large icon.

When filling in the WNDCLASSEX structure to be used in registering
your window class, set the hIcon member to the system large icon
(usually 32x32) and the hIconSm member to the system small icon
(usually 16x16). For more information about class icons, see Class
Icons.

